# Bremsstrahlung explanation using wave model of electromagnetic radiation

Tags: photons, photon-emission

Bremsstrahlung is the electromagnetic radiation produced by the deceleration of a charged particle, when deflected by another charged particle. As per Young and Freedman 13e,

> Experimentally, not all x-ray frequencies and wavelengths are emitted: Each spectrum has a maximum frequency and a corresponding minimum wavelength The greater the potential difference the higher the maximum frequency and the shorter the minimum wavelength.

Why can't the wave model explain Bremsstrahlung?

Is it because all frequencies of electromagnetic radiation are expected to be emitted during the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Bremsstrahlung is predicted by the classical electromagnetism, its prediction is not compatible with what one observes in atomic spectroscopy.

You are right: (part of) the problem lies with the emission frequencies (the other part is that one cannot have a stable atom in classical electrodynamics).

In classical E.M. radiation emitted by a moving charge has the same frequencies that its motion has: uniform motion has $0$ frequency, periodic motion with frequency $\omega_0$ produces radiation with frequencies $N\omega_0$ with N natural. If the particle is accelerated only for a time interval of lenght $T$ one can show that emission frequencies are all the $\omega \lesssim \frac{1}{T} $ (continuous spectrum).

None of these explain frequencies observed in spectroscopy, that are discrete and following Rydberg's law of $\omega \sim const( \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2}) $ for $n,m$ naturals.